# Python OCR Function reducing the size of the image, how do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, opencv, python

I am path walking through a folder and finding pdfs. I am then changing those PDF's to text. Before passing the image through the OCR function, I am doing some image processing by turning to greyscale, and cropping the image so that some aesthetic elements are not present. The first page of each pdf is slightly different than the second - last page of PDF, so each PDF page is filtered through a if - else statement.

Passing the first JPEG through the OCR function works perfectly across different documents, but each time I am passing the JPEG through the OCR function, it only passes the first document image again. It creates the second,third... but only passes the first jpeg through the function. I have been trying to debug this all morning, so please excuse all the extra info. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the results for the pass through the function with OCR.

````
executing first page number loop
(3000, 2064)
(2064, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_1.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_2.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_3.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_4.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_5.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_6.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_7.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_8.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_9.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_10.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
11
0
executing first page number loop
(3000, 2064)
(2064, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_12.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_13.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_14.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_15.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
executing this chunky piece of code
<class 'PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile'>
jpegs/file_16.jpeg
(1714, 2064)
6
0```





              article_number = 0
saved_image_num = 0
text_file = 'txt_files/' + 'article'

print(saved_image_num)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('articles'):
    for file_ in files:
        if file_.endswith('.pdf'):
            article_path = str(root) + '/' + str(file_)
            pages = convert_from_path(article_path, dpi=300)
            length_of_article = len(pages)
            page_number = 0
            for page in pages:
                if page_number == 0:
                    print('executing first page number loop')
                    name = 'jpegs/file_' + str(saved_image_num) + '.jpeg'
                    page.save(name, 'JPEG')
                    saved_image_num += 1
                    page_number += 1
                    image = image_2_gray(name)
                    print(image.shape)
                    img = crop_page_1(image)
                    print(img.shape)
                    image_ocr(img, text_file + str(article_number) + '.txt')
                    if page_number == length_of_article:
                        article_number += 1
                        print(page_number)
                        page_number = page_number - length_of_article
                        print(page_number)

                elif page_number >= 1:
                    print('executing this chunky piece of code')
                    name_ = 'jpegs/file_' + str(saved_image_num) + '.jpeg'
                    page.save(name_, 'JPEG')
                    print(type(page))
                    saved_image_num += 1
                    page_number += 1
                    print(name_)
                    img1 = crop_page_2_through_end(name_)
                    print(img1.shape)
                    image_ocr2(img1, text_file + str(article_number) + '.txt')
                    if page_number == length_of_article:
                        article_number += 1
                        print(page_number)
                        page_number = page_number - length_of_article
                        print(page_number)
````

Answer (score 0):

My conditions were all messed up. Change the sequence of the final if conditions.